# str_replace in a array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building a simple system in CodeIgniter for a client of mine. I want to use `str_replace` to replace a tag like {company_name} into a value but I seem to cannot get this to work.

My current code is:

```
<?php

$this->db->where('id', '1');
$data = $this->db->get('pages');

$output = array('row' => $data->row());
$this->template->load('frontend/template', 'frontend/page', $output);
```

My try was:

```
<?php

$this->db->where('id', '1');
$data = $this->db->get('pages');

$output = str_replace(
    array("{company_name}"),
    array("Sample company"),
    $data->row()
);

$this->template->load('frontend/template', 'frontend/page', $output);
```

But I think I am currently on the wrong path as nothing displays anymore and I want some help or explanation on what I am doing wrong here. Thank you.

Comment: afaik you don not have to use arrays for `str_replace` if you are only trying to replace one value with another. Also, can you make sure that `data->row()` contains the exact string `"{company_name"}`?

Comment: what does $data->row() contain ?  is it a string or an array?

Comment: It is a array. It contains all the fields from the database. For example, the ID: the title, the content, the creation data, the edit date. But I only use title and content in my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at php [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function .

If you want to replace all items in the array, you need to iterate over it :

```
foreach($data->row() as $key=>$value){
$data[$key] = str_replace("{company_name}","Sample company",$value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what about using a MySQL function [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
$this->db->select("SELECT REPLACE(field, '{company_name}', 'Sample company') FROM pages ");
```